# Does it need to include `None = 0` in Bit Flag Enumeration types?

Tags: c#, enums

From the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types), the value `0` assigns to elements mean "no flags are set" (e.g. `None = 0`), so why should I use it in my enum? Can I declare an enum without it?

I tried to write an enum without `None = 0`, and the compiling was successful.

Comment: You can do without `None` (especially if you can guarantee that at least one flag should be set); but for better readability, maintenance you'd rather add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a strong suggestion, not a rule. Good reasons to follow the <strike>rule</strike> suggestion:

- Consistency. It's part of the [recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum) that Microsoft have published since day 1 of .NET and is followed by almost all enums you'll find in the framework and in third party code.
- It means `default(YourEnum)` has a value defined within your enum.
- It means `YourEnum variable = 0` (the only [Implicit enum conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-enumeration-conversions)) has a value defined within your enum.

Reasons not to follow the rule:

- It's not enforced by any compiler warning or error
- ...

So, yes you can, but I'd strongly recommend against doing so.

Unlike other values of the underlying numeric type, you can obtain `0`s *without* explicit casts (as the bullets above show). You *will* encounter these values, and so you *need* to write code that deals with that `0` anyway. Give it a name. Give it *the* recommended name.

(Of course, I'd also recommend being exhaustive in all enum related code and have sensible ways of dealing with all out-of-range values but the non-0 ones are only obtainable via explicit casts)